# log4j and Weblogic Server : Logs not getting generated

Tags: log4j, weblogic, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

I have multiple ears,For certain Ears I want log4j details to be picked from Weblogic level and for certain application I have application level log4j.xml bundled with ear.

1. Copied wllog4j.jar and Log4j-x.x.x.jar to Server classpath
2. Added the following JAVA_OPTION in

> startWebLogic.sh -Dlog4j.Configuration=Mylog4j.xml

and add the "Mylog4j.xml" in the Server Classpath
as :

```
    SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS}" -Dlog4j.Configuration=Mylog4j.xml
    SAVE_CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:/apps/myfiles/MyLog4j.xml"
```

1. For application which have application level log4j.xml ,I have mentioned prefer-application-packages in weblogic-application.xml

   ```
   <prefer-application-packages>
   <package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name> 
   </prefer-application-packages>
   ```

But the logs are not getting generated for those application which has there log4j.xml

Also,Just for info : Applications are using slf4j/commons-logging and log4j

Please suggest !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to classloading : Below line in weblogic-applicaton.xml does the trick.

```
    <prefer-application-packages>
     <package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name> 
     <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name> 
     <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name> 
    </prefer-application-packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps 
1) copy log4j.jar and wllog4j.jar in server lib folder
2) copy your log4j.xml in server domain folder
3) change setDomaninEnv.xml to point to your log4j.xml file ex: LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE="${DOMAIN_HOME}/log4j.xml"

Comment: Will this definitely solve the issue? Sounds more like a comment to me!